AWS AipGateway lambda authorizer Lambda using dart to validate Google ID token after using sign in with Google
I have a Flutter app where my users can sign in with Google. I get the ID token from Google and everything is just perfect.
I'm hosting my flutter app on AWS Amplify and I'm using lambdas, all written in dart with dart images. Again everything is working well.
Now I would like to write a dart lambda that will be used as an ApiGateway authorizer.  I need to verify the Google ID token that I got when my user signed in with Google.
I know I have to send the token to my lambda and I know how.  The problem is that I didn'find any dart package that would validate the Google Id token.  Google has some libraries for Java, python, PHP, Nodejs but none for dart.
Anyone with a good idea for getting a dart lambda to act as an authorizer and be able to verify the Google ID token?
